# ordered list allign like the rest in css and html

Tags: html, css, list

I need 1.5.2.1 in the list also alligned like the rest, what am I doing wrong? Please help me to adjust the css code to align the ordered list indent as seen at 1.5.2.1, I dont know what im doing wrong.

```css
ol {
 counter-reset: item;
 padding: 0; 
 margin: 0;
 margin-left: 20px !ie7;
}

ul {
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
 list-style: none;
}

li span, li {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li:before {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 content: counters(item, ".") ".";
 float: left;
}
ol > li {
 counter-increment: item;
 
}
ol li:before {
    
 width: 50px;
}
```

```html
 <ol>
  <li><strong>Introduction</strong>
    <ol>
      <li><span>This document...</span></li>
      <li><span>In the event...</span></li>
      <li><span>We...</span>
        <ol>
          <li><span>"Acknowledgment...</span>

            <li><span>"Deliver"/ "Delivered"/...</span>

              <ol>
                <li>where...</li>
              </ol>

            </li>
        </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>TITLE TWO
      <ol>
        <li>text 2 one</li>
        <li>text 2 two</li>
        <li>text 2 three</li>
        <li>text 2 four</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>TITLE THREE
      <ol>
        <li>text 3 one</li>
        <li>text 3 two</li>
        <li>text 3 three</li>
        <li>text 3 four</li>
        <li>text 3 five</li>
        <li>text 3 six</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You did not have the `<span>` tag right around 1.5.2.1's text.

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <span>
            where you are already in possession of the Vehicle, confirming our mutual intention (as evidenced by a written Delivery Note which we will                 issue to you and which must be signed and accepted by you) that you shall cease holding the Vehicle in your possession for and on our behalf and retain possession of the Vehicle with the intention of holding the Vehicle in your name on your behalf as owner of the Vehicle; or
        </span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot your span tag inside ol and li tag

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20px !ie7;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li span,
li {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li:before {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  content: counters(item, ".") ".";
  float: left;
}

ol>li {
  counter-increment: item;
}

ol li:before {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><strong>Introduction</strong>
    <ol>
      <li><span>This document serves as an annexure to the Standard Terms and Conditions
and its sole purpose is to set out the specific conditions applicable to the type
of Finance Product you have selected to finance your Vehicle ("Annexure A").</span></li>
      <li><span>In the event of any inconsistency between the provisions of the Standard
Terms and Conditions and the provisions of this Annexure A, the provisions of
this Annexure A will prevail.</span></li>
      <li><span>We confirm that you have selected a CONTRACT PURCHASE Finance
Agreement for purposes of financing the Vehicle as described in the Schedule.</span></li>
      <li><span>Capitalised terms used, but not defined in this Annexure A shall have the same
meaning assigned to those terms as in the Standard Terms and Conditions.</span></li>
      <li><span>For purposes of this Annexure:</span>
        <ol>
          <li><span>"Acknowledgment of Receipt" means a written document acknowledging
receipt together with any inspection documents and Value Added Tax forms
issued by us when you Redeliver the Vehicle to us, which acknowledgement
confirms that you have relinquished possession of the Vehicle and have Retransferred
ownership of the Vehicle to us such that we become the owner of
the Vehicle (on the basis that we retain the Vehicle's registration papers in
the manner contemplated in this Agreement);</span>

            <li><span>"Deliver"/ "Delivered"/ "Delivery" means the delivery of the Vehicle by us
to you by either:</span>

              <ol>
                <li><span>where you are already in possession of the Vehicle, confirming our mutual
intention (as evidenced by a written Delivery Note which we will issue to you
and which must be signed and accepted by you) that you shall cease holding
the Vehicle in your possession for and on our behalf and retain possession of
the Vehicle with the intention of holding the Vehicle in your name on your
behalf as owner of the Vehicle; or</span></li>
              </ol>

            </li>
        </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>TITLE TWO
      <ol>
        <li>text 2 one</li>
        <li>text 2 two</li>
        <li>text 2 three</li>
        <li>text 2 four</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>TITLE THREE
      <ol>
        <li>text 3 one</li>
        <li>text 3 two</li>
        <li>text 3 three</li>
        <li>text 3 four</li>
        <li>text 3 five</li>
        <li>text 3 six</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Ah thanks guys, this comes from late nights, and not seeing stupid mistakes!!!!

Comment: haha. it happens, I'm glad it was quick and easy.

Comment: lol yea man, thanks a mill!